# Weird button behavior: wrong behavior on first click. works after

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a button that should sort and update a list on click. When clicking it the second time everything works like intended(the ordered list gets displayed), but when I click it for the first time(and only the first time) the list appears twice. So it returns ABCABC instead of just ABC. After the second time its always ABC as intended.

What's the reason for that?

Thanks in advance

List.js

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { data } from "./data/testdata.js"
import { render } from "react-dom";

let list1 = []

let d 
function sortList(){
  d = data.sort((a, b) => {
    return a.rec_loss - b.rec_loss;
});
d.reverse()
list1 = []
d.forEach((element) => list1.push(<li key = {element.name}>{element.name + " " + element.rec_loss + " " + element.shap}</li>))
return list1
}

export default function List({data}) {
    data.forEach((element) => list1.push(<li key = {element.name}>{element.name + " " + element.rec_loss + " " + element.shap}</li>))
    const [myData, setMyData] = useState(list1)
    return (
      <>
        <ul>{myData}</ul>
        <button onClick = {() => setMyData(sortList)}>Sort The list</button>
      </>
    );
  }
```

index.js

```
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { data } from "./data/testdata.js"
import App from "./App";
import List from "./List";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const test = 
<>
<App />
<List data={data}/>
</>
render(test, rootElement);
```

Comment: generally is not recommended to directly manipulate shared variables outside the component's state, as it can lead to unpredictable results. I believe that's the reason for that wrong behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got a couple of things mixed up here, hopefully my answer can help straighten them out.

I don't think React VDOM nodes should be stored in state. In general, you should stick to plain objects and arrays for state. So when you call the `useState` hook, it should only store the initial data passed to the `List` component.

```js
export default function List({data}) {
    const [myData, setMyData] = useState(data);
    ...
```

Secondly, you shouldn't rely on variables in the module scope as mentioned by @chris-g in the comment. So your variable `list1` is in module scope, but actually isn't needed at all. In general, for variables to be reactive they should be stored in props, state, or context.

Here's a refactored `List` component that illustrates the difference.

```jsx
export default function List({ data }) {
  const [myData, setMyData] = useState(data);

  function sortList() {
    let sorted = [...myData].sort((a, b) => -1 * (a.rec_loss - b.rec_loss));
    setMyData(sorted);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <ul>
        {myData.map(element => (
          <li key={element.name}>
            {element.name + ' ' + element.rec_loss + ' ' + element.shap}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
      <button onClick={sortList}>Sort The list</button>
    </>
  );
}
```